# BST delete doesn't actually delete

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I've got this delete function that takes a node in a BST as a parameter to delete it. It checks for three cases before doing anything:

- If the node has no children - then just delete the node
- If the node has one child - then just replace the node with the child
- If the node has two children - find the smallest node in the right tree, replace it with the node we want to delete (essentially deleting it) then delete the smallest node we found

The first two cases work, but not the last case with two children. The code for just that case is as follows

```
AccNode* smallest = pointer->getRight();
bool foundSmallest = false;

// Find the smallest node in the right branch
while (foundSmallest == false) {
    if (smallest->getLeft() == NULL && smallest->getRight() == NULL) {
        foundSmallest = true;
    } else {
        if (smallest->getLeft() == NULL && smallest->getRight() != NULL) {
            smallest = smallest->getRight();
        } else {
            smallest = smallest->getLeft();
        }
    }
}

// Replace the node we want to delete with the data in
// smallest node we found and delete smallest node in that tree
pointer->setData(smallest->getData());
delete smallest;
```

To further debug, Xcode has some pretty cool tools that let you visualise the tree, and I discovered something pretty interesting. Before we get to the line `delete smallest;` the smallest node in the tree looks like this

[image: Smallest node pre deletion]

After we delete the line it looks like this

[image: Smallest node post deletion]

So what's going on here? Am I messing up something with the way I'm using the pointers?

---

**Edit:** I just realised something. In the image on the tree post deletion, in a folded up section the right node is no longer NULL and has value now. I opened it up and it is the entire right branch from the node we wanted to delete from the beginning (so the right branch of the original pointer). So I feel like I'm definitely doing something wrong with the pointers now. Any clue as to what it is?

Comment: So the problem is that some data thing gets changed after you deleted it? That's ok. You can't rely on it being the same even if you don't own it anymore.

Comment: Rolled back the edit changing the code after answers about it had already been posted. @SteppingHat: **please don't change any aspects of a question** after answers have been posted. You can amend the question but don't *change* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to null the pointer (in the parent node of smallest) pointing to smallest. This leaves that pointer as a **dangling pointer**, a pointer pointing to already deallocated memory. The debugger shows the arbitrary content for such memory, in many cases just what was there earlier.

You need to keep track of the parent node.

Also, the current logic branches right when it can't branch left and branching right is possible. But that leads to a node with larger value, including all its children. So this logic is ungood.

An alternative to copying data, deleting and nulling pointer in parent, is to rearrange the tree (move the smallest node to the place where you have the node you really want to delete)  and then just delete the node you really want to delete. This has the two advantages of generally doing less work, and keeping other pointers to the nodes valid.

Niklaus Wirth's book “Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs” is little gem for this. I read its original edition based on Pascal. I believe there is a free electronic edition now based on Oberon.

---

General advice: in modern C++ it can be a good idea to use `nullptr` instead of the macro `NULL`. It's more type safe in general.

Also, instead of

```
foundSmallest == false
```

just <sup>(1)</sup>write

```
not foundSmallest
```

or

```
!foundSmallest
```

---

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> With at least one not entirely standard-compliant compilers you have to include the `<iso646.h>` header in order to use the reserved words `and`, `or` and `not` as operators. But, this can be done via forced include directive in the command line. It doesn't need to show in the code.</sup>

Comment: For the sake of my code, how exactly would I set the pointer to null? I already have the parent as a node but don't know what to do with it. And for the sake of your alternative, could you provide an example of some sort? Thanks!

Comment: @SteppingHat:  Like, `parent->setLeft( nullptr )`. Or, `parent->left = nullptr`. Except that with corrected logic it gets more complicated, because the minimum node can have a right child, and essentially the switcheroo technique of copy data then won't work.

Answer (score 0):

After you've deleted the memory held by `smallest`, it isn't valid to read anymore. It's just garbage data. It may make sense, it may not, but there's no guarantee of anything.

Algorithmically, as Cheers has pointed out, you've forgotten to remove the `smallest` node as a child of its parent. In other words, its original part is still pointing to it. You can fix this by keeping track of a `parent` node.

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to null the pointer as Cheers answered.
2. I don't think your algorithm of finding smallest node is correct. To find the smallest node of a BST, you should NOT go right as any node of the right sub-tree is no less than the node itself. The correct way should be keep going left until it has no left sub-tree which means no node is less than that one.

Comment: I just realised this and had already fixed finding the smallest node. I also updated it to cheers answer of using !foundSmallest in the while statement. That whole part of the code was a quick and dirty write up with focus on actually deleting the node at this stage with intentions to clean it up later :P

Comment: Actually it is not necessarily null because the smallest node may have a right sub-tree. And I prefer modifying pointers than replacing data.